# Assigning a variable to a function return?

Tags: python-3.x, function, variables

I came across the following function:

```
def load_words():
    """
    Returns a list of valid words. Words are strings of lowercase letters.

    Depending on the size of the word list, this function may
    take a while to finish.
    """
    print("Loading word list from file...")
    # inFile: file
    inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r')
    # line: string
    line = inFile.readline() # reads one entire line from a file (as a string)
    # wordlist: list of strings
    wordlist = line.split()
    print("  ", len(wordlist), "words loaded.")
    return wordlist 

wordlist = load_words()
```

I don't understand the assignment of the function load_words() to the variable wordlist? When the variable is assigned, the function gets executed.

Is wordlist the function load_words()? Or is it the return of the function load_words()?

Comment: `wordlist = load_words()` is conceptually not different from `inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r')` - a function is called and whatever the function returns is assigned to the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give:

```
wordlist = load_words()
```

you are running the function `load_words()` and assigning the return value `wordlist` to the variable `wordlist` outside the function.

---

- You can also run functions without assigning it to a variable, like:

  load_words()
  but here the `wordlist` variable you return, is not stored anywere in the python (i mean the current shell) for further use. The `wordlist` inside the function is a local variable and is valid only inside the function.
- So when you give `wordlist = load_words()`, wordlist now becomes a global variable, so that you you call it when you require it.